# An alternative to the "edit has been made" banner

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today, when I was going to edit a question and was just about to click `edit` button, another edit to that question was made.

Well, when the banner `an edit has been made...` appears, it "bumps" the question downward a bit. This is why I failed to click `edit`, and clicked one of the question's tags accidentally.

This was not the first time it happened for me. It is surely not something that happens often, but I'd still like to suggest another way of indicating a newly edited post: a different background color.

So, when an edit is made to a post, instead of displaying a banner that pushes all content downward, the background color of the post would change.

Well, now that I think about this, some people would probably wonder *why* the color of a post changed, so I guess it would be still useful to include the text `an edit has been made...` somewhere too - but without bumping the content.

I understand that the bump *might* be useful in situations where you've scrolled to the bottom of the page, and the question or an answer is edited. In that case, you clearly notice the bump (if you happen to be looking at the screen just at that moment) and then scroll up to see what was edited.

In conclusion, I'm not sure: Would this suggestion be better or worse than the current style?

Comment: The only solution I can think of is taking it out of the flow of the document and just having it appear at the top of the post over the content. Basically it would cover up the first line of the post. I can't imagine this bothering anyone, but I'm sure it would at some point.

Comment: @animuson that sounds an awful lot like "orange-y" which I thought had been burninated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Slidey appeared at the very top of the entire page, and the color and size made it obnoxious. It actually still exists on Area 51. ;)

Comment: This sounds very minor. I say just go back to the page and try again (two extra clicks is no biggie).

Comment: @animuson ah, I never visit Area 51. I also observed slidey on the main site a couple of weeks ago (and you may have commented on it IIRC). I was very surprised to see it.

Comment: It already existed back in 2012? I encountered the same message today.

Answer (score 4):

Eh, I see the bump/mis-click as a minor, uncommon inconvenience. Plus, odds are if someone else just made an edit, you likely won't really have to anyway. I find it more annoying to spend a few minutes on fixing up a post to find that I was beaten to it by a few seconds. Forcing you to miss your click would save you the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I like the color suggestion, but I think the current bump behavior is better overall - only because I'm usually more interested, while crafting my own answer, if edits have been made to the question. The bump makes it clear that *something* has happened, and I can go investigate if it was the qeustion or one of the other answers.

A color change would not be visible to me in that situation.

I don't think it's ever happened to me that I have clicked the wrong button because of a content shift on the current post. That doesn't mean it doesn't happen to anyone, but I suspect it's quite rare.